# Are apply, arguments, bind, etc. part of the internal prototype of a javascript object?

Tags: javascript

I keep reading about the inaccessible internal prototype of javascript objects and am wondering whether this is related to the methods you find on the javascript data types: Object, Array, String, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the "inaccessible internal prototype" is not *directly* related. Objects have a "prototype chain". This is how JavaScript does inheritance.

```
A  ->  B  ->  C  -> null
```

So failed property lookups on Object `A` will continue the lookup on `B`. A failed lookup on `B` will continue on `C`. If it fails on `C`, `undefined` is returned.

The key thing is that the act of transferring the lookup from object to object is automatic. You don't do it manually.

How this works, is that each object keeps a reference to the next object in the chain, via an internal property referred to as `[[Prototype]]`. This is not a property that can be directly accessed according to the ECMAScript standard. So that's what is referred to as the *inaccessible internal prototype*.

```
A[[Prototype]] == B

B[[Prototype]] == C

C[[Prototype]] == null
```

---

So it may *seem* related because you are indeed able to get methods from the `.prototype` object of those constructors, but the internal inaccessible prototype is referring specifically to those internal object references that make it all work.

---

While that internal property is not directly accessible, ECMAScript 5 does let the developer ask for the object that is held by that property. You can do this using the `Object.getPrototypeOf()` method.

```
var foo = new String("foobar");

var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(foo);
```

So now the `proto` variable will hold a reference to the object that the internal `[[Prototype]]` of the string was holding. That object happens to be the object found on the `.prototype` property of the `String` constructor.

```
console.log(proto === String.prototype); // true

console.log(foo.hasOwnProperty("slice")); // false

console.log(foo.slice === String.prototype.slice); // true
```

---

So you can note the following:

- the value of the `[[Prototype]]` internal property of the string is the same as `String.prototype`,
- the string itself does not have a `.slice` property,
- the string does *inherit* a `.slice` property from `String.prototype`.

It inherits it because of that implicit lookup described above. So instead of:

```
A  ->  B  ->  C  ->  null
```

...the prototype chain looks more like:

```
       // vv--slice is here
foo  ->  String.prototype  ->  Object.prototype  ->  null
```

Since `foo` has no `.slice`, it looks at its internal `[[Prototype]]`, finds that object, and continues the lookup there.

---

***EDIT:** Updated to use `var foo = new String("foobar");` instead of `var foo = "foobar";` so that `Object.getPrototypeOf()` would accept it.*

*Primitive values, like a string primitive (no object wrapper) automatically gets converted to the object wrapper when you access properties on it, so the above description applies to both primitives and objects.*

Comment: this is helping big time.  One thing I encountered is when I try:
 var foo = "foobar";

var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(foo); I get the following error:
TypeError: Object.getPrototypeOf called on non-object

Comment: @JohnGalt: Ah, yes. Change `var foo = "foobar";` to `var foo = new String("foobar");` so that you get the object wrapper. I'll update too. This is another hidden behavior. When you have a `"foobar"` *primitive* value assigned to `foo`, and access a property on it, it gets automatically converted to the `new String()` object wrapper. I forgot that `Object.getPrototypeOf()` specifically needed that wrapper.

Comment: So, if you want to add a property (that can be some value or function) to an object (e.g. myObject.someProperty) so that the added property is only in memory once, add that property to an object's prototype property (e.g. myObject.prototype = {someProperty: value} and then to enable another object's inheritance of that prototype property by first creating the object and then use newObject.prototype = myObject.prototype. Now myObject is part of newObject's prototype chain?

Comment: @JohnGalt: Partially. Remember, don't think of `myObject.prototype`. That would be accessible. Think of `myObject[[Prototype]]`, which is *not accessible*. The object itself has no `.prototype` property. The `.prototype` is a property on a function that is used to set up the relationship between a new object being made and that function's `.prototype`. So to add something to the `[[Prototype]]` of `myObject`, you would need to use `var p = Object.getPrototypeOf(myObject)` to fetch the value of the inaccessible `[[Prototype]]`, and then add methods to that.

Comment: ...The `.prototype` property on a *function* exists as a really weird and unintuitive way of setting up the internal `[[Prototype]]` relationship between objects. `String` is a constructor function. `String.prototype` points to an object that new string objects will point to with their internal `[[Prototype]]` property.

Answer (score 2):

`apply` and `bind` are part of `Function.prototype` (see all methods in [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4)). So they are only available on function objects, not on any object.

`arguments` is a [special kind of object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.6), available as a local variable only within functions, at runtime, when they are called.

Comment: On a side note, I'm trying to answer the question in the title, but I'm not really sure what you're actually trying to understand here...

Comment: I think I was/am confusing the `prototype` property and the internal prototype of an object.  I thought (mistakenly) that the methods I see for an object in the console (e.g. Object.apply) were part of this prototype property.

Comment: Ah, that's a common confusion. The easiest way to think of it is that all objects have an internal [[Prototype]], but only constructor functions have a prototype property. See Blue Sikes' answer for details. @JohnGalt.